# ¿Problema con script SQL Server? Ayuda

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente codigo de sql server con las tablas sitio, barrio, localidad y provincia. El scrip tira algun error de sintaxis? cual es el resultado que arroja? gracias hace horas estoy luchando con esto

```
SELECT S.razonSocial, count(*)
FROM Sitio S, Barrio B, Localidad L, Provincia P
WHERE S.barrio = B.idBarrio
     AND B.idLocalidad = L.idLocalidad
     AND L.idProvincia = P.idProvincia
     AND P.nombre = ‘Cordoba’
GROUP BY S.cuil
HAVING count(*) > 5
```

Comment: Hola, ¿Por qué no ejecutas la consulta en tu base de datos para ver el error que pueda lanzar y verificar que este bien?

Comment: porque es un ejercicio donde no me dan la base de datos y crearla tiraría aun mucho mas tiempo que no dispongo. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

el problema que tenes me parece que es en las comillas, así aparentemente funciona:

```
SELECT S.razonSocial, count(*)
FROM Sitio S, Barrio B, Localidad L, Provincia P
WHERE S.barrio = B.idBarrio
     AND B.idLocalidad = L.idLocalidad
     AND L.idProvincia = P.idProvincia
     AND P.nombre = 'Cordoba'
GROUP BY S.cuil
HAVING count(*) > 5
```